# Optimize convolution operation for ARM using NEON

Tags: c, optimization, arm, simd, neon

Can someone guide me to optimize the Convolution of a filter on an image using the benefits of ARM Neon intrinsics in C? I have already implemented this in traditional C, however, I need to time-optimize the code for faster image processing on ARM with NEON support. The resources available on the internet are very limited for the algorithm implementation on ARM using NEON using C.

I need to convolve a 3x3 filter with the image. The main problem I guess is the loop constraints to access the 3x3 matrix of the image. NEON intrinsics help us to load 8 bytes of data at a go, but how to take benefit of this, in order to access the 3x3 matrix?
[image: Convolution Example]

For now, I'm accessing the 3x3 image matrix like this,

```
for(i=1;i<width;i++) // i = rows                                                                                                       
        {                                                                                                             
                if(i!=1)                                                                                                                       
                        fseek(fp, 1078+(width*(i-1)), SEEK_SET);                                                                               
                for(j=1;j<height-1;j++) // j = columns                                                                                         
                {                                                                                                                              
                        if(j!=1)                                                                                                               
                                fseek(fp, 1077 + (i*width) + j , SEEK_SET);                                                                    
                        for(k=0;k<9;k+=3)                                                                                                      
                        {                                                                                                                      
                                data[k] = getc(fp);                                                                                            
                                data[k+1] = getc(fp);                                                                                          
                                data[k+2] = getc(fp);                                                                                          
                                //fread(buf, sizeof(char), width - 3, fp);                                                                     
                                fseek(fp, width - 3, SEEK_CUR);                                                                                
                        }                                                                                                                      
                        pixel = vld1_u8(&data);                                                                                                
                        pixel_last = data[8];                                                                                     
                        result = vmul_u8(kernel,pixel);                                                                                        

                        for(k=0;k<8;k++)                                                                                                       
                                sum += result[k];                                                                                              

                        sum += pixel_last * kernel_last;                                                                                       
                        sum = sum/9;                                                                                                           
                        sum = sum > 255 ? 255 : sum;                                                                                           
                        imageData[i*width + j]= sum;                                                                                           

                }                                                                                                                              

        }
```

Comment: You can posy your question here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: First, separate your file I/O from your filtering code. Use one function to read your image data into a source buffer in memory, then apply your filtering routine so that it reads from the source buffer and writes its output to a second buffer. This will make the filtering much easier to implemement, and also will allow you to benchmark your optimised filtering code separately from the (much slower) file I/O.

Comment: I stopped reading at `intrinsics`.

Comment: Thank you @PaulR ! Your solution works fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from @PaulR in the comments above did the trick. Reading the image data at once, in a buffer, and then applying the filter algorithm reduced the timings to nearly 10 times.

Here is what I did,

```
fread(imageData, sizeof(unsigned char), imgDataSize, fp);                                    

for(i=0;i<width;i++) // i = rows                                                                       
        {                                                                           
                start_1= clock();                                      
                for(j=0;j<height;j++) // j = columns                                    
                {                                                                                    
                        for(k=0;k<9;k+=3)                                                                      
                        {                                                           
                                data[k] = imageData[i*width + j];
                                data[k+1] = imageData[(i+1)*width + (j+1)];             
                                data[k+2] = imageData[(i+2)*width + (j+2)];                          
                        }                                                                                      
                        pixel = vld1_u8(&data);                                     
                        pixel_last = data[8];                                       
                        result = vmul_u8(kernel,pixel);                                                        

                        for(k=0;k<8;k++)                         
                                sum += result[k];                                       

                        sum += pixel_last * kernel_last;                                                       
                        sum = sum/9;                                                
                        sum = sum > 255 ? 255 : sum;             
                        newimageData[i*width + j]= sum;                                 

                }                                                                                              
        }
```

Comment: There is still a lot more you can do to make the above filter code more efficient, but if this is fast enough for your needs already then you can just leave it as it is.

Comment: Can you explain what more can be done @PaulR ? I'd like to know. The more efficient, the better.

Comment: Well there's way too much redundant scalar code, and you're iterating through memory non-contiguously, to name just two major issues. If you post an appropriately tagged question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com (since this is working code), and make sure it has a [mcve] based on your current functional code, then I and others can give you some concrete suggestions on improving it.